# Check For String/Set of Strings(Separated by |) available in List of strings Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of String like

```
Countries = ['United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Luxembourg', 'Canada', 'China', 'Brazil', 'Hong Kong', 'Indonesia', 'Japan', 'India', 'Ireland', 'Germany', 'Australia', 'France', 'Switzerland', 'Malta', 'South Korea', 'Russia', 'Taiwan', 'Bermuda', 'Turkey', 'Mexico', 'Not Applicable', 'Argentina', 'South Africa', 'Malaysia', 'Thailand', 'Singapore', 'Qatar', 'Italy']

str1 = 'United Kingdom'
str2 = 'United States|China|Hong Kong|Italy'

len([col for col in Countries if str1 in col]) > 0
returns TRUE
```

How can i check whether all countries in str2 are available in the `Countries` list?

Comment: `TRUE` must be `True` in `python`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the all statement to check if every country in the str2 is in Countries:

```
Countries = ['United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Luxembourg', 'Canada', 'China', 'Brazil', 'Hong Kong', 'Indonesia', 'Japan', 'India', 'Ireland', 'Germany', 'Australia', 'France', 'Switzerland', 'Malta', 'South Korea', 'Russia', 'Taiwan', 'Bermuda', 'Turkey', 'Mexico', 'Not Applicable', 'Argentina', 'South Africa', 'Malaysia', 'Thailand', 'Singapore', 'Qatar', 'Italy']

str1 = 'United Kingdom'
str2 = 'United States|China|Hong Kong|Italy'

str2 = str2.split("|")

if all(i in Countries for i in str2):

   #do something
```

Comment: This is what i was lookinf for

Answer (score 2):

You can find out by creating `set` from list using builtin `set` function.

`set.issubset
Docstring: Report whether another set contains this set.
Type:      method_descriptor`

```
In [3]: str2 = str2.split('|')
In [8]: set(str2).issubset(set(Countries))
Out[8]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for str in str2.split('|'):
  if str in Countries:
    print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Countries = ['United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Luxembourg', 'Canada', 'China', 'Brazil', 'Hong Kong', 'Indonesia', 'Japan', 'India', 'Ireland', 'Germany', 'Australia', 'France', 'Switzerland', 'Malta', 'South Korea', 'Russia', 'Taiwan', 'Bermuda', 'Turkey', 'Mexico', 'Not Applicable', 'Argentina', 'South Africa', 'Malaysia', 'Thailand', 'Singapore', 'Qatar', 'Italy']

str1 = 'United Kingdom'
str2 = 'United States|China|Hong Kong|Italy'

str3 = str2.split("|")
if set(str3) <= set(Countries):
    return True
```

Comment: That should be `<=`, not `<`